# Flutter users should run 'flutter pub get' instead of 'pub get'

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, get, dependencies

When i try to open most of downloaded flutter app in android studio it keeps telling me 'Pub get' has not been run and when i press 'get dependencies' or upgrade dependencies' it shows me that error . I have upgraded android studio and flutter and dart to the latest version

Error :

```
C:\Dart\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat get
Resolving dependencies...
Because wisgen depends on flutter_test any from sdk which doesn't exist (the Flutter SDK is not 
available), version solving failed.

Flutter users should run `flutter pub get` instead of `pub get`.
Process finished with exit code 69
```

This is the pubspec.yaml of the project

```
name: wisgen
description: A Wisdom Generator
#for release:       flutter build apk --release
#for release:       flutter build appbundle --build-number=2

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as                         CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
#         https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.4+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  cached_network_image: ^1.1.1
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.3+4
  share: ^0.6.2+1
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.0.0"
  flutter_bloc: ^0.21.0
  equatable: ^0.6.1
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  #  The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.2"
  mockito: ^4.1.1
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/ball-col-3.png"

#flutter pub get
#flutter pub pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  assets:
    - assets/

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: Go to the top menu 'Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean' and check if you are getting any other errors, like setting flutter sdk in Android studio

Comment: @Nuts the Problem has been fixed thamk you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after i update flutter i got this issue i tried everything nothing worked for me

**then deleted .package** and hit save in pubspec ,,
work like a charm

Comment: I have flutter v3.3.7, the .package thing can't be located, can you please help out?

Answer (score 2):

`Go to the top menu 'Tools > Flutter > Flutter Clean'`

Normally there is a problem with Flutter SDK not being set up (can be other problems too)

[image]